# Custom tableViewCell

Tags: objective-c, xcode, swift, cocoa, nstableview

I'm going nuts here.

I've been trying to follow any kind of tutorial about Cocoa tableViews and I'm ending up with the same problem over and over again.

My project:

1. 2 xib files: MainMenu, MasterViewController (MasVC)
2. Table set up in MasterViewController  (which is connected to MasVC.xib)
3. MasterViewController view added as subview in AppDelegate:

   ```
   masterViewController = MasterViewController(nibName: "MasterViewController", bundle: nil)
   window.contentView!.addSubview(masterViewController.view)
   masterViewController.view.frame = window.contentView!.bounds
   ```

Now I'm trying to create a custom TableCellView so I add new file called CustomCell that inherits from TableCellView

I change the class for TableCellView in MasVC.xib to be "CustomCell" and I drop two labels inside that cell. I also set up an identifier ("SetCell")

When I try to make IBOutlets connecting these labels to my CustomCell file nothing happens - I can't do that.

So I drop new object into MasVC.xib and set its class to CustomCell -> Now I can make those connections.

Inside viewForTableColumn
(xxxx and yyyy just for test purpose):

```
let cell: CustomCell = tableView.makeViewWithIdentifier("SetCell", owner: self) as! CustomCell
cell.firstLabel.stringValue = "xxxx"
cell.secondLabel.stringValue = "yyyy"
return cell
```

I launch my project, add first thing to my table and kaboom. It highlights

```
cell.firstLabel.stringValue = "xxxx"
```

and displays error:

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
(lldb)
```

What did I do wrong?

**EDIT1**

It seems that it doesn't create those labels at all, but why?

[image]

**EDIT2**

[image]

Views above.

I managed to solve it (not the best solution probably...)
As I mentioned - I added an object and conected it to class TwoLabelCell (instead of CustomCell). This way I was able to drag IBOutlets to TwoLabelCell file. Then I had to connect my labels with TableViewCell by dragging connection from Two Label Cell (displayed in a view posted above right below SetsColumn) outlets (those displayed on the right hand side panel) to actual labels and a label looks like this now:

[image]

I do have warnings like this now:

```
Unsupported Configuration: Outlet 'secondLabel' of 'Two Label Cell' is connected to 'Second Label,' an invalid destination (Object may be repeated at runtime.)
```

but it works.

Comment: Hey, just a quick question - are they meant to be text fields or labels?

Comment: I dragged labels to my project but they are displayed as TextFields and it's ok.

Comment: Does your custom `TableCellView` belong to `TableView` in Interface builder? Let me know the hierarchy of the views.

Comment: Jabeom Gyeong - I added new edit